# Passing PHP values from one place to another

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
  define ('ACCESS', 1);
  require_once 'database.php';

  $db = new Database();
  $sql = 'SELECT Drn,Src,Tit,Sub FROM Img_Compositos_Cersize WHERE Drn > :id'; 
  $parameters = array(':id' => 0);
  $results = $db->getArray($sql, $parameters);

  foreach ($results as $index => $result){
    $html  = '<div class="compositosType_brandContainer">
                <div class="compositosType_brand">
                  <p><span class="compositosType_subtitlePrefix">'.$result['Tit'].'</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="compositosType_title">'.$result['Sub'].'</span>
                  </p>
                  <img class="compositos_image" src="'.$result['Src'].'" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>';
    echo $html;
  }
```

... and I have this HTML:

```
<div class="compositos_DBitem_lightbox">
  <p class="compositos_infoImage_title">Rock name</p>
  <p class="compositos_infoImage_subtitle">Rock type</p>
  <img class="compositos_infoImage"src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

When I click the **`.compositosType_brandContainer`** (PHP), it pops-out the **`.compositos_DBitem_lightbox`** (HTML). Right now the **`.compositos_DBitem_lightbox`** is empty, but I want it to display the same common PHP strings, which are:

```
- '.$result['Tit'].' ---> .compositos_infoImage_title
- '.$result['Sub'].' ---> .compositos_infoImage_subtitle
- '.$result['Src'].' ---> .compositos_infoImage
```

The jQuery code that pops-out the **`.compositos_DBitem_lightbox`**:

```
    $(this).addClass('compositos_highlighted').animate({'width':'70%', 'height':'70%', 'top':'10%'}, 100, 'swing')
    .find('p').animate({'font-size':'73%'}, 100, 'swing',
      function(){
        $this.animate({'width':'100%', 'height':'100%', 'top':'-4.5%'}, 100, 'swing')
        .find('p').animate({'font-size':'110%'}, 100, 'swing',
          function(){
            $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.compositos_lightboxBackground').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox').one('click', function(){
              $(this).fadeOut(300);
              $('.compositos_lightboxBackground').fadeOut(300);
            });
          }
        );
      }
    );
```

I should also mention that the PHP dynamically creates a bunch of the **`.compositosType_brandContainer`** divs.

Comment: Please include the code (javascript?) that "pops out" the HTML.

Comment: Question is incomplete..due to popups script...

Comment: Added the jQuery code.

Comment: Did you try to print_r the result from the DB?

Comment: @bksi, could you give me a live example, please?

Comment: What live example? I talk about debugging. If you don't have a result from DB your DIV will be empty. So you have to be sure you have a result from DB. so use print_r($results); to see if you have real result from DB

Comment: Sorry about that. The PHP code I've posted is working - all I need is what I asked for.